# Unable to find element when uploading file in TestCafe

Tags: testing, file-upload, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

enter image description here

I wrote code below

`let browseButton = await Selector('input').withAttribute('id', 'card_image_1583116662160_11.707407693474106');
    await t
    .click(Selector('.fa.fa-image'))
    // upload img
    .setFilesToUpload(browseButton,'../../artifacts/uploads/boba.jpg')`

but the result is

```
1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

         | Selector('input')
       > |   .withAttribute('id', 'card_image_1583116662160_11.707407693474106')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a dynamic ID in your `Selector`. In this case you should create your `Selector` based on CSS classes or other non-dynamic attributes. Please refer to this documentation section: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/.

The following example may be also useful: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/element-properties/check-element-markup.js. The example shows how to access DOM properties and verify them with assertions (you can "debug" [each level of the `Selector` hierarchy](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html)).

Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

**UPDATE**: [Select Elements With Dynamic IDs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#select-elements-with-dynamic-ids)

**UPDATE 2**: [RegExp example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withattribute) - `Selector('input').withAttribute('id', /card_image_\w+/)`

Comment: Yes, i tried let browseButton = await Selector('input').withAttribute('id', 'card_image_\w+/'); but still getting the same  "The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree".

Comment: You need to use slashes in your regular expression, [for example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withattribute): `Selector('input').withAttribute('id', /card_image_\w+/);`